# how to walk a directory application MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

How to walk a directory application project ASP.NET MVC 3 ?

For example: I must find one file in derectory MyApp.WebUI/controls

Comment: Please add more detail on what you are trying to achieve and, more importantly, on *what you have done to try and achieve it*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) method. Or if you already know the name of the file you could directly access this file. In order to calculate the absolute path to this directory/file you should use the `Server.MapPath` method:

```
var location = Server.MapPath("~/MyApp.WebUI/controls");
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(location);
...
```